# Normalization and mark the threshold

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

The colorbar ranges of an image in matlab ranges from 0.55 to 1. Is it possible to normalize it so that it ranges from 0 to 1.

Comment: Your data is probably within the range, try to scale it to 0 1

Comment: I would like to add the code associated with this, probably you can help me to modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A = rand(1e3,1); %// get random numbers
A(A<0.55)=[]; %// delete everything below 0.55
minA = min(A(:));
A = A-minA; %// translate to the lower point at 0
A = A./max(A(:)); %// stretch to range to 1
disp(max(A(:))),disp(min(A(:)))
     1

     0
```

This simply scales your code by subtracting the minimum to translate your range to start at `0`, then is divided by the current maximum to stretch the range to extend to `1`.

Comment: my `a` is a matrix of 'p x q'.

Comment: Thank you so much, is it possible for you to answer my second question i.e. define a line like I have done using black line in the image.

Comment: In my y-axia, I have values ranging from 0 to 25. I want to draw a line as I have done in the figure. The black line you see is done by me in paint. Can I do something like this in matlab?  I also want to store them in a matrix. I have tried using `argmax` but it did not work, but I believe that `argmax` will work.

Comment: kindly see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35114272/draw-a-line-and-store-the-y-value